# PHP asynchronous multiple file write and read

Tags: php, http, curl, http-post

I am using a cURL based php application to make requests to another webserver that does asynchronous requests. So what I am doing is creating files with the name as .req with the info I will need on the return and  as the identification in the request. The requests are done using HTTP-XML-POST. The file is written using: -

```
file_get_contents(reqs/<databaseid>.req, FILE_APPEND);
```

What happens is that while the requests are being generated in bulk (about **1500** per second), the responses start coming back from the webserver. The response is caught by a another script which received the  from the response and opens the request file based on it using: -

```
$aResponse = file(reqs/<databaseid>.req);
```

Now what happens is that in about 15% of requests, the file() request fails and generates a log entry in apache log like this: -

```
file(reqs/<databaseid>.req): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <scriptname> on line <xyz>
```

It has been verified using a cleaner script that runs later that the file did exist.

Any ideas?!!!

Comment: So, you are sending the request and writing the request and when you get the answer you open the file you wrote the request in?

Comment: yes, the remote server is...well...remote and not accessible any other way and closed to any other data that I might want it to return.

So I need to hold on to the data in this way.

Answer (score 1):

There are some functions to handle simultaneous file access such as [flock()](http://es.php.net/flock) but it's normally easier to simply use a database. Any decent DBMS has already worked it out for you.

Comment: Sorry, I just corrected the Transaction per second. As we have to maintain atleast 800 per second, we cant go the DB route, because we would be talking atleast 1500 inserts per second and then about 1200 updates per second because of the responses.

So, would need a carrier grade DB server which we dont have right now...!

Comment: Furthermore, the issue is not file locking because there is one file PER request and we are creating the file using `file_put_contents(filename, FILE_APPEND)` BEFORE sending the actual request.

Comment: eh? you can fetch files from a remote server faster than you can log them in a local database?

Comment: Really?! Thanks for the comment but this was 4 YEARS ago!

We went around and re-did the server ourselves, adding both sync and async modes to it in addition to a bulk mode. The bulk mode was specifically designed (and is now successfully) handle over 1000TPS and is working really well.